# How to enlarge JOptionPane windows

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Is there any way to change the size dimensions of a `JOptionPane` window in java? I tried looking around online and didn't see anything. It would be for a simple `showInputDialog();` window.

Comment: [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163188)? What's wrong with the the enclosed components preferred sizes?

Comment: *"Is there any way to change the size dimensions of a JOptionPane window..?"*  Sure it's easy.  Give it different sized content.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a better approach is to consider to use JDialog instead JOptinionPane.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(); 
String categories[] = {"Test", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};
JList list = new JList(categories);

scrollpane = new JScrollPane(list);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
panel.add(scrollpane);

scrollpane.getViewport().add(list);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollpane, "Test List", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```